# Magento 2.3.2 Product Image Missing after version updating from 2.2.1

Tags: magento2, product-images, magento2.3.2, catalog-product

I have updated the Magento version to **2.3.2**. After updating the Magento, the product images are not visible.

The product catalog images are coming from the old cache file directory.

I have done the following.

> 1. Remove pub/media/catalog/product/cache . (Removing this folder frees
>      up space.)
> 2. Run bin/magento catalog:image:resize to generate a new image cache

Still, I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: Have you checked pub/media is having correct permissions? Check your browser console to see for the images and check for the images in pub folder

Comment: Yeah. I have the images in pub folder with correct permission.

Comment: So what response are you getting in network tab ?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors on console tab.

Comment: Open your network tab in your browser and reload the page and check what response you are getting for the image and check the path URL to see if it exits

Comment: Images are not exists in the current image cache path(pub/media/catalog/product/cache/1dbe12bf27f8c5651168069dc17144/n/e/new.jpg). Original images are exist in the folder(pub/media/catalog/product/n/e/new.jpg). I have to regenerate the image path.

Comment: Goto your admin flush catalog images cache and CSS/Js Cache. Once cleaning it flush magento cache. It would solve your problem unless you are using any third party caches/PWA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A common issue is that Magento is looking for the pictures in the old cache files that are missing after the upgrade as the cache was cleared.

Try below actions:

1. A catalog reindex. Follow below article for reindex steps.

> https://support.weltpixel.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000355673-How-to-reindex-your-Magento-2-store-from-admin-or-SSH-CLI

2. Re-generate the image catalog by using the command below via CLI:

> php bin/magento catalog:images:resize

I hope this will help, Once you done please update me

Comment: When i'm running this command - 

php bin/magento catalog:images:resize

File '/var/www/html/proj/pub/media/catalog/product/b/u/button_image_1.jpg' does not exist.

Comment: So, I have manually adding the missing images. 

Those images are deleted products. I dont know, why its showing error on removed product images.

Comment: Becz,Deleted product images are still referenced in the following table.

catalog_product_entity_media_gallery,

catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value,

catalog_product_entity_media_gallery-value_to_entity.

Comment: You can remove references to deleted images with te folowing query: DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery WHERE value_id IN (
    SELECT cm.value_id FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery cm LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value cmv ON cm.value_id = cmv.value_id WHERE cmv.value_id IS NULL)

Comment: @DennisvanSchaik MYSQL returns Table 'catalog_product_entity_media_gallery' is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data

Answer (score 4):

I had this exact same problem with Magento 2.3.2

For me it was product thumbnail images that had the wrong cache hash path and was showing the std Magento image placeholder.

I was using a custom theme.

No matter how many times i ran "php bin/magento catalog:images:resize" still the same problem.
I found that the images were being generated using the Luma theme etc/view.xml instead of the custom theme etc/view.xml file.

The problem.
When viewing my custom theme in the browser which uses different size images to Luma theme, Magento could not find the images and shows 404 error.

The fix.

1. Replace Luma themes etc/view.xml with my custom theme etc/view.xml
2. Using SHH run "php bin/magento catalog:images:resize

I took me a week to find out how to fix this, but it all work fine now.

Comment: "I found that the images were being generated using the Luma theme etc/view.xml " you saved me with this. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

I had faced **similar** issue and resolved it by running the following command:

```
php bin/magento sampledata:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Although I was working with sample data, not sure about real data.

I hope it helpful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following article if you are using Magento Commerce

[Cached images are not loaded after 2.2.X to 2.3.X upgrade](https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360027822171-Cached-images-are-not-loaded-after-2-2-X-to-2-3-X-upgrade)