# Images are not shown on Magento 2.3.5 for the product page

Tags: magento2, product-images, image-resize

I have an issue with the images. On the category pages images are shown for the products, but on the PDP page the img is missing. Instead i got the placeholder img. On the admin, the img is set to `base`, `small` and `thumbnail`.
I followed the possible answers from here: [Magento 2.3.2 Product Image Missing after version updating from 2.2.1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/281314/magento-2-3-2-product-image-missing-after-version-updating-from-2-2-1), like doing:

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

or

```
bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

But none of them worked for me. The cache is also cleared. Can you give me some advice what should I check more ? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how, but on the store level, the images were hidden, so updating them to visible by this query:

```
update catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value set disabled = 0 where disabled = 1;
```

fixed my issue with the images

Comment: Is it need to run any magento commands after these query run?

Comment: @ArunprabakaranM nope . I didn't . Just clear the cache after the update